# pushPage先にあるons-switchを、動的に操作したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

MonacaでOnsen UIを用いて開発しています。

アプリ画面上部右端にあるアイコンをタップすると、
setting.html
というページをpushPageするようにコーディングしています。

setting.htmlへ遷移した際に、setting.htmlにあるons-switchの初期状態を
データベースから読み込んだ値にしたいのですが、
反映させるタイミング、方法がイマイチわからず
ご教示いただければと思います。

過去スレによると、pushPage先で何かするときにはpushPage元でons.readyを使ったり、
AngularJSを使うのかな…となんとなく思っているのですが。。。

ちなみに、記載したコードには記述がありませんが、
データベースからの読み込みは、top.htmlにインクルードしたjsの中で、
ajaxを用いてjsonで取得しています。
(値が正常に取得できていることは確認済み)

以下、コード。

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ncmb-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <!-- <script></script> -->
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" id="navi" page="login.html"></ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<ons-page>
    <div class="login-form"><br><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="メールアドレス" value="">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="パスワード" value="">
        <br>
        <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" Onclick="login();" >ログイン</ons-button>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="message" class="login-message"></div>
</ons-page>
```

**top.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ncmb-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script></script> -->
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" id="navi">
        <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
                <div class="center"></div>
                <div class="right"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" class="tab-setting" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('setting.html')"></div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            <ons-list>
                <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="top-list-item-container">
                    <div class="top-list-item-left">
                        <img src="" class="product-img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="top-list-item-right">
                        <div class="top-list-item-content">
                            <div class="product-name">あいうえお</div>
                            <div class="devuser-name">鈴木一郎</div>
                            <div class="last-send">更新日：2016/01/08 11:11</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="top-list-item-container">
                    <div class="top-list-item-left">
                        <img src="" class="product-img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="top-list-item-right">
                        <div class="top-list-item-content">
                            <div class="product-name">かきくけこ</div>
                            <div class="devuser-name">鈴木二郎</div>
                            <div class="last-send">更新日：2016/01/07 11:11</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

**setting.html**

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button></ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center">設定</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <div class="settings-header">プッシュ通知</div>
    <ons-list modifier="inset" class="settings-list">
        <ons-list-item>プッシュ通知<ons-switch modifier="list-item"></ons-switch></ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: `ons.readyを使ったり、AngularJSを使うのかな…となんとなく思っているのですが。。。`まずそれにチャレンジしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: oTakさん
回答ありがとうございました。1ヶ月経過してしまいましたが…
ons.readyやAngularJSを使ってやってみようとは思ったのですが、ちょっと時間的な制約があり、未知の領域で試行錯誤することができない状態でした。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageがPushされる時に"prepush"というイベントが発生します。
http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#EventHandling

ons-switchにvar属性を付けてJavaScriptから使えるようにして、
setCheckedメソッドでDBから読み込んだ値を設定するとよいかと。
http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-switch.html

（追記）
使用するイベントはprepushでなくpostpushでした。すみません。
またはons-pageの初期化が完了すると発生するpageinitイベントで。

Comment: user13314さん
回答ありがとうございます。今回は時間的制約があり、他の人間がons.readyやAngujarJSを使用しない方法で実装してしまったのですが、後々のことを考えるとお教えいただいた方法で作り直したほうがいいような気がしておりますので試してみます。ありがとうございました。